# Calc Order Sum from Orderlines

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sum

Hi I'm trying to calc the sum of an order.
I got an order with and Id, and a number of Orderlines.

```
Order
ID       OrderDate  CustomerName


OrderLine
OrderID  ProductId   Amount    Price
```

I would like to make a select statement, where I get the following output.

ID, OrderDate, CustomerName, OrderTotal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `JOIN`, `GROUP BY` and `SUM`. Something Like:

```
SELECT o.ID,
       o.OrderDate,
       o.CustomerName,
       SUM(ol.Amount * ol.Price) AS OrderTotal
FROM   [Order] o
       LEFT JOIN OrderLine ol /*If not all orders may have items */
         ON o.ID = ol.OrderID
GROUP  BY o.ID,
          o.OrderDate,
          o.CustomerName
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is incomplete. But I will try to guess the remaining missing parts.

Let's assume that you have two tables. One table has Orders , we will call it `tbl_orders` and another that has the details of the orders and will call it `tbl_details`.

here is how I would do it

```
select a.ID,a.OrderDate,a.CustomerName, sum(b.Amount * b.Price) OrderTotal 
from tbl_orders a, tbl_details b where b.orderId = a.ID 
group by a.ID,a.OrderDate,a.CustomerName
```